# Using celery to update a progress message?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am looking for libraries that can help in displaying a progress message so a user knows how far along the task is. I found Celery, and I was wondering if it is possible to use Celery to display a progress message that updates on the page during the load. For example: "Loaded x amount of data" and enumerate x.

Answer (score 0):

Celery is meant to do background jobs. That means it cannot directly interact to update your web page. To achieve something like what you described, you would need to store the progress data externally (like say into a database) and then query this data source in the webpage via AJAX. Yeah, it is a bit complicated.